# python interpreter brew vs default

Tags: python, macos

I have macOS Sierra and I want to use the python which is installed by homebrew but not the default Apple's python. According to the instructions in this site (Link: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x), I use

```
sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Then, I move /usr/local/bin at the beginning of the file so Homebrew binaries take on system binaries. So, the output is:

```
/usr/local/bin  
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

However, there is no change and it uses system binaries yet:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

What Should I do?

Comment: Homebrew doesn't install an executable named `python` -- it only installs `python2` or `python3`. I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. I tried which python2 instead and I got what I needed.